# Simple Html Dom - исключить ссылки с определенным анкором? PHP

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Как в Simple Html Dom исключить ссылки с определенным анкором?

Подробнее о скрипте:

1. Foreach берет нужные ссылки.
2. Если в ссылке есть анкор "скачать" или "смотреть", то не добавлять строку в массив.

Вот со вторым пунктом проблема.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113232/xpath-to-exclude-elements-that-have-a-class

Answer (score 2):

```php
$html = file_get_html('<URL>');

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    if (preg_match('/(скачать|смотреть)/iu', $element->plaintext)) {
         // Пропускаем анкоры, которые содержат слова "скачать", "смотреть"
         continue;
    }

    // Логика обработки остальных анкоров
}
```